# Eclipse debugger crashes when debugging a project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

I am working on a java application in eclipse Indigo. I was working and debugging the project with no problems but at one attempt, the jvm gave an error and the run window crashed. After that now when I run the debugger on that specific project, the main program loads after 10-15 seconds and when it does, it hangs and closes down the program upon any action. The program runs fine in "Run Mode". I check debugger for one other project in the workspace and it works fine for that, but is only giving problem for this one specific project.

I have tried running Eclipse again, clean and build project again, remove extra breakpoints and try again but the problem exists. How can I solve this problem, it is really annoying me as I have to deliver the project and without debugging I cannot track the data coming in and out.

Comment: Reinstall eclipse. You can update it at the same time, if you're still using indigo.

Comment: actually I have subversive configured with this version to share the code, and re-installing the new version will remove the configuration of the project.

Comment: You don't know the SVN configuration for the project? I find that hard to believe. Anyway, with eclipse it's often easier to reinstall than fix, and in this case you might end up saving time (as well as getting a brand new version of Eclipse).

Comment: I know the configuration, I was installing subversive plugin for the new version of eclipse and it gave repostory error again and again so I configured it with an older version. Updating might cause that problem again

Comment: How about the Subclipse plugin? One was out of date, Subversive or Subclipse, but I forget which.

Comment: Try deleting .metadata directory under your workspace and then import your project again.

Comment: Thank you So much @amicngh . This worked for me. I deleted the .metadata directory and import project again and it works perfect

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Eclipse with the `-clean` option ("eclipse.exe -clean"). This will cause Eclipse to clean the workspace metadata and rebuild it from the projects. This should take care of this problem.