# Importing Pandas Terminates Eclipse PyDev Debugger when I add PyInstaller

Tags: eclipse, pandas, debugging, pydev

I'm getting an odd termination in the PyDev debugger in Eclipse.  Running the following works fine.

```
import pandas as pd

def main():
    print('hello')
    pd.Series([])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I debug the same code with a breakpoint on line 1 it works so far.

[image]

If I step over one step (F6 or pressing the button) however it terminates itself with an ugly exit value (-1073741819), but no error in the console.

[image]

This happens when I debug almost any of the code I have except for the most basic things.  I tried [running "eclipse.exe -clean"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006937/eclipse-debugger-crashes-when-debugging-a-project) but it didn't seem to clear the problem.

Edit:
It is clearly installing pyinstaller that is the issue

```
conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller
```

if I revert to a previous revision the debugger works again.  Oddly I don't even need to restart eclipse for it to fix itself.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is a ran a "conda install -c conda-forge pyinstaller" earlier this morning.

Comment: Using "pip install pyinstaller" works fine... I am so confused.